# jquery-ui dialog don't display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

In my spring application, I have one dashboard page from where the sub-pages are opened in popup windows implemented using the jquery-ui dialog. The code for this it's below:

```
function open_dialog(url, dialog_div) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url
    }).done(function(data){
        var id_dialog_div = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
        var dialog_box = $('<div id="dialog-'+id_dialog_div+'" class="dialog" title="Basic dialog"> <p> <span id="text'+id_dialog_div+'"></span> </p> </div>');
        $('#box').append(dialog_box);

        $( dialog_box ).dialog({
              minHeight: 720,
              minWidth: 640,
              show: {
                effect: "fadeIn",
                duration: 1000
              },
              hide: {
                effect: "fadeOut",
                duration: 1000
              }
        });

        var $temp  = $('<div/>', {html:data});

        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { title: $temp.find('title').text() } );
        $( dialog_box ).find('#text').html( $temp.remove('head').html() );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { height: 480 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( { width: 640 } );
        $( dialog_box ).dialog( "open" );
    });
}

$(document).on('click', '.popup', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var action = $(this).attr('href');
    var target = $('#popup');
    open_dialog(action, target);
});
```

When I run the application, and click in the link, the dialog is opened, but the window stays completely blank, despite the page which should be displayed in the window is read (I can verify this by the network monitor from firefox).

Anyone can tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: `$( dialog_box ).find('#text')` should be `$( dialog_box ).find('#text' + id_dialog_div )`

Comment: I also think there is something wrong with $temp.remove('head').html(). Remove method will remove the head element and all the element in it, so it leaves nothing. So there is no data could be shown.

Comment: @OQJF it's not wrong: I want add to the dialog only the content of the `<body>` of the page. But right now this is not working: when I run the application, all the code from the page is displayed inside the `<div>`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. Do you find the solution?